# cordova-ionic app take geolocation in background - android and ios

Tags: android, ios, cordova, geolocation, ionic-framework

I want to build an app, using cordova and ionic, that is capable to provide geolocation. According to my research there are some issues with providing information about geolocation when the app is running in background. Can you give any hints or advice about how can I resolve this?  Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, background geolocation is possible with this plugin: [cordova-plugin-background-geolocation](https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation).

Add [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/) to interact with the plugin via AngularJS wrappers.

Example with [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/) & [cordova-plugin-background-geolocation](https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) (example from ngCordova Docs):

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaBackgroundGeolocation) {

  var options = {
    // https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation#config
  };

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

    // `configure` calls `start` internally
    $cordovaBackgroundGeolocation.configure(options)
    .then(
      null, // Background never resolves
      function (err) { // error callback
        console.error(err);
      },
      function (location) { // notify callback
        console.log(location);
      });


    $scope.stopBackgroundGeolocation = function () {
      $cordovaBackgroundGeolocation.stop();
    };

  }, false);
});
```

Comment: I just installed plugins and ngCordova and i want to test with this example.... please tell me, if I include this---->>desiredAccuracy: 10,
        stationaryRadius: 20,
        distanceFilter: 30,
        notificationTitle: 'Background tracking', // <-- android only, customize the title of the notification
        notificationText: 'ENABLED', // <-- android only, customize the text of the notification
        activityType: 'AutomotiveNavigation',
        debug: true, // <-- enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
    stopOnTerminate: false  in "options{};" should work ?

Comment: Yes adding that to the options object should allow you to test the plugin. You'll have to play around with the options to find values that work for your app.

Comment: Hi...i wrapped "geolocation-background" in my "$ionicPlatform.ready(function()" and seems to work. I used this solution because with ngCordova "device ready function" doesn't work. But, because this function is out of "$scope" cover(out of  app.controller), my question is, how can i detect a click event in this function ?   thanks... i hope that is well explained :)))

Comment: You can use `$ionicPlatform.ready()` within a controller. Just be sure to include it in your controller definition: `module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaBackgroundGeolocation)`.

Comment: No problem, glad to hear you got it working. Good luck with your project.